# Change IIS culture when deploying asp.net site with octopus deploy

Tags: octopus-deploy

I'm using octopus deploy with the IIS deploy option and I want to set the culture and ui culture to spanish
There are any options to change this settings from Octopus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's configurable via web.config

`<globalization culture="es-AR" uiCulture="es-AR" />`

Comment: He's asking how to do it through octopus, not just how to change the web.config

Comment: LOL, I was asking, and I can resolve this, setting the value in the web.config (you can use Octopus for that), so I don't need to modify the value in IIS